# Google Cloud Platform logs download not completing

Tags: google-cloud-platform

While trying to download logs from Google Cloud Platform it does not complete and seems to get stuck at an arbitrary point. How can the logs be exported in such cases?

[image]

Comment: Could you provide the method you're using to export logs and any error messages you received.

Comment: Have tried the "Download" option in the console web view, and then export 10000 logs as JSON from the pop-up window.

Comment: I am having the same issue, even when my query finds only 59 records.

Answer (score 0):

When downloading huge log volumes, sometimes the process may be interrupted or stopped. In order to handle it steadily you can try other alternatives, which are mentioned below.

> 1. **gcloud CLI**: Google Cloud provides the gcloud CLI for users to be able to create and manage Google Cloud resources, including logs,
>    via the command line.
> 2. **Pub/Sub** : In the Pub/Sub model, a topic is used to direct logs that need to be exported outside of Google Cloud and a subscription is
>    used to forward the logs to their final destination

The Doc [Google Cloud Log Extraction](https://www.sans.org/blog/google-cloud-log-extraction/) written by Megan Roddie will give you more information on this.

Comment: But it's not for large volumes only. I have a total of 9 log entries I need to export and the download just hangs forever saying 9/500. If I tell it to give me maximum 9 then it ends as soon as it reaches 9.